# Get view Info Fullcalendar V5

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am trying to get some information on the fullcalendar view. In particular I need to get 'activeStart' and 'activeEnd' every time the user change month. I'm currently using Fullcalendar V5 and I followed the guide at this link https://fullcalendar.io/docs/view-render-hooks

but I was unable to trigger an event when the user change month(
Fullcalendar is rendered correctly). Using viewClassNames the event is triggered only if there are events in the month.

Comment: "I need to get 'activeStart' and 'activeEnd' every time the user change month"...why, exactly? If you're using this to try and fetch new events for each month, this is the wrong approach to that task (because fullCalendar already provides separate functionality for that).

Comment: I have to send a request to google calendar api to load the events for a single month. Google calendar api allow the client to load max 2500 events so I need to load them by month. To do that I need to know wich month fullcalendar is showing. Where I can get this type of information?

Comment: Like I said, fullCalendar already has functionality specifically for handling the loading of events - and it supports gradual loading of only events which are relevant to the currently visible month (or other date range, if you use the week view, for example). In fact, if your google calendar is public, there is even a ready made connector which you can use to automatically read from there. Take a look at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-source to see what your options are and look at the specific articles. If you still have any uncertainty after that, you can ask me a more specific question

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the event that generates the data I need. It is called from the events and return the displayed range date inside fullcalendar.

```
events: function( info, successCallback, failureCallback ) {
        console.log(info.startStr)
        console.log(info.endStr)
}
```

That return this json:

{start: Mon Sep 28 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0200, end: Mon Nov 09 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0100, startStr: "2020-09-28T00:00:00+02:00", endStr: "2020-11-09T00:00:00+01:00", timeZone: "local"}

Comment: This still isn't the correct way to link events to your calendar. Did you read what I provided?

Comment: @ADyson Using this event I can get the start date and end date to request google calendar api with the correct date format. This solve my problem. The calendar that I use is private so there is also a dedicated google authentication behind the process. I read the link that you provide me but i manage to solve the problem with the code above

Comment: Nonetheless if that's the case you should be using https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function to run the call to the API using the dates provided in the callback. That's the robust way that fullCalendar recommends in order to efficiently fetch events when they're actually needed

Comment: @ADyson I edit the answer to match the correct way to get this information with what was said in your comment

Answer (score 0):

ADyson is right that the correct way to achieve this specific behavior is to load events in the events callback. However, if anyone else stumples onto this question I figured that I could add how to actually get this information without the callback.

For FullCalendar v5 this is accessible through calendar.view.activeStart where calendar is your calendar object created with new Fullcalendar.Calendar().

For older versions it is accessible through: ('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').start